# Should I canculate the instantaneous velocity of average velocity for the question?

Tags: reflection, geometric-optics, mirror-symmetry

A man running at a speed 5m/s is viewed in the side mirror of radius of curvature R=2m of a stationary car. Calculate the speed of image when the man is at a distance of 9m from the mirror.

Comment: There are only going to be two instants when the man will be 9m from the mirror,. And judging by the presented problem, the answer would be the same for either instant.

Comment: Can you eloborate.? I asked whether to calculate instantaneous velocity or average velocity.